# How to hide SQL Plus password in Python script

Tags: python, sql, sqlplus

I created Python script which truncate Oracle table. I use SQL Plus, but the problem is that I have to hide password which is plain text now. I have arguments like these:

```
db_name = "DB_NAME"
db_user = "DB_USER"
db_password = "DB_PASS"
```

Then I run command like:

```
sqlplus_delete_table = 'echo "TRUNCATE TABLE ' + db_user + '.' + table + ' DROP STORAGE;"'
sqlplus_connection = db_user + '/' + db_password + '@' + db_name
os.system(sqlplus_delete_table + ' | sqlplus -s ' + sqlplus_connection)
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is password. As I know, SQL Plus does not use jceks files. So what are other solutions to hide password?

Comment: Try getting environment variables or loading from some other config script/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a solution like Django's `SECRET_KEY`, which I store in a file that is not in the project repository. From this file I load the keys like this in `settings.py`:

```
with open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'etc/secret_key.txt')) as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```

In the above example the contents of the text file is just the key, but you can use structured formats such as JSON, YAML, or even a Python file and import it.

Example of Python secret file:

```
# secret.py
DB_PSSWD='pswd'
DB_USER='user'
```

In your source code simply:

```
import secret

print(DB_USER)
```

Example of YAML secret file:

```
# secret.yaml
db_psswd: pswd
db_user: user
```

In your source code simply:

```
import yaml

with open('secret.yaml') as yaml_secret:
    rules = yaml.load(cfg)
print(rules['db_user'])
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux it's possible to create bash-script like:

```
# sql.env
export db_PSSWD='pswd'
export db_USER='user'
```

Before running python, run bash-script to initialize environment variables:

```
source sql.env
```

Then, in `python`:

```
db_psswd = os.environ.get("db_PSSWD")
db_user = os.environ.get("db_USER")
```